# py2exe with unicode characters

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, special-characters, py2exe

I'm trying to make .exe made by py2exe display diacritics, for example:

```
gender = raw_input(u"Błąd! Podaj płeć jeszcze raz: ")
```

Since my system uses cp1250 by default and I've set coding in this script to UTF-8, adding *u* before the string makes it display properly in the IDLE. The .exe is still a mess, though. Changing the coding only sometimes changes how diacritics are displayed. I've tried also various combinations of `.edcode()`, importing `unicode_literals` and changing the special characters to their bytes representative in unicode (`\u0142` for ł etc.) Is there a way to make it work?